# Is there a way to update multiple documents to add certain number to one column without using loops

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js

I'm using SailsJS with MongoDB and have a model like this:

```
module.exports = {
   attributes: {

       name : { type: 'string' },
       openDate: { type: 'date' },
 }
}
```

And there are hundreds of document in the database.
Now I have a array with a list of names. And needs to add 30 days to openDate whose name is the list.
And is there a way to do this without creating a loop and within the loop, geting the name and update the openDate one by one, but use one collections.update to fulfill that?
Currently I only have code to find all the document whose name is in the list, but not sure what to do next.

```
Accounts.find({
            name:{ $in : nameList}
        }).exec(function(err, data) {


});
```

Comment: You mean that each name's openDate should be incremented by 30 days?

Comment: Is this a one time update? If so, just do it in the mongo shell.

Comment: No, it's recurring. And every time the name list passed from the front end is different.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can apply the same date to all of your records (which i believe is not what you want) then the answer is no. There is no mechanism to do that, but it should be (You or somebody should propose it on their github repo), at least to pass an array of ids to the criteria and a matching array of values as the second parameter of update, and according to the docs you can pass an array of values, but I've test it, and it throws an error (at least on mysql adapter), and there are no test to back up that functionality.

All examples use **lodash** , **es6 arrow** functions and assume you have a fn to **increaseDates**)

So if you can use the same value, then you could do this:

```
Accounts.find({name:{ $in : nameList}}).exec(function(err, data) {
  // error handling here
  var criteria = _.map(data, 'id'); // same as pluck
  Accounst.update(criteria,  {openDate: increaseDate(x.openDate)}).exec(...);
});
```

Guessing that the above is not an option, you would need to use something like async series or parallel, likes this:

```
Accounts.find({name:{ $in : nameList}}).exec(function(err, records) {
      // error handling here
      tasks = _.map(records, (x)=> Accounts.update(x.id, {openDate: increaseDate(x.openDate)}, callback));
      async.parallel(tasks, function(err, results){});
    });
```

In my case i use [async/await](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait) so is a matter of doing this and the updates will run in sequence:

```
  async(()=> {
    records = await (Accounts.find({name:{ $in : nameList}});
    _.each(records, (x)=> await (Accounts.update(x.id, {openDate: increaseDate(x.openDate)}));
  })()
```

or to run them in parallel, something like this

```
  async(()=> {
    records = await (Accounts.find({name:{ $in : nameList}});
    tasks = _.map(records, (x)=> Accounts.update(x.id, {openDate: increaseDate(x.openDate)}));
    await (tasks)
  })()
```